# Use an observable store and a component input with Angular

Tags: angular, rxjs, store

I developed a custom angular store using a `BehaviorSubject` and I'm using like this:

```
export class UserFaceComponent {

    @Input()
    public id: any;

    public presence$: Observable<boolean>;

    constructor(private _store: Store) { }

    public ngOnInit() {
        this.presence$ = this._store
            .select(s => s.users.presences)
            .pipe(
                map(p => p.includes(this.id))
            );
    }
}
```

This way, when the store changes, the `presence$` observable emits a new value. It works well, however, the `id` passed to the component could also change. Say there is a list of user on the page and when the user selects one of them, it updates a variable `selectedUserId` that is passed to the `UserFaceComponent`. This would be the same component as before but `id` would be updated.

This means that I have to create a subject in my component, subscribe to the `onChange` hook and emit on this subject when id changes. Then, I have to merge this observable with the one above and then emit the new value.

This would work but it is pretty cumbersome and I don't want to be forced to do this for each component made with this approach... I'm thinking about it for a while but I can't find another solution to tackle this...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I came accross the same requirement several times and unfortunately there is no simpler solution as your `onChange`-`subject` approach. I read once there was a suggestion of an `ObservableInput` decorator, but it never was implemented.

Besides your approach there is just one another way to do this, it is not really simpler, just different. This alternative approach uses input getters and setters instead of the `ngOnChanges` lifecycle hook to update the subject.

```
private _id: BehaviorSubject<string> = new BehaviorSubject<string>();
@Input()
set id(value: string) {
  this._id.next(value);
}
get id(): string {
 return this._id.value;
}
```

Comment: Not exactly the answer I was looking for (I was hoping for a magical solution I guess hehe) but this version is shorter than mine. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You could assign a new observable to your variable if you subscribe with the `async` pipe. The `async` pipe automatically unsubscribes from its current observable and subscribes to the new one if you assign a new observable to its input.

```ts
export class UserFaceComponent {

    @Input()
    public id: any;

    public presence$: Observable<boolean>;

    constructor(private _store: Store) { }

    ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
      if (changes['id']) {
        const currentId = changes['id'].currentValue
        this.presence$ = this._store
          .select(s => s.users.presences)
          .pipe(
            map(p => p.includes(currentId))
          );
      }
    }
}
```

```html
<div>{{ presence$ | async }}</div>
```